# Python Beautiful Soup 4 Get Children of Element with .select()

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The .select() element allows me to get an element off a web page based on a css selector, but this will search the whole web page. How would I use .select() but search only children of a specific element. E.g.:

```
<!-- Simplified example of the structure -->
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="foo">foo content</div>
        <div class="bar">bar content</div>
        <div class="baz">baz content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- We can't assume that foo, bar, and baz will always be there -->
        <div class="foo">foo content</div>
        <div class="baz">baz content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="foo">foo content</div>
        <div class="bar">bar content</div>
        <div class="baz">baz content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want a way to say:
for `<li>`[0] foo contained the value `"foo content"`, bar contained the value `"bar content"` etc..

Currently my solution is the following:

```
foos = soup.select("div.foo")
bars = soup.select("div.bar")
bazs = soup.select("div.baz")

for i in range(len(foos)):
    print("{i} contains: {} and {} and {}".format(i=i, foos[i], bars[i], bazs[i]))
```

This works for the most part. But it completly falls apart when an element is missing from one of the li's. Like I showed in the HTML, we cannot assume that the three bar, baz and foo elements will be present.

Thus, how would I search only children of the lis. Thus I could do something like this:

```
for i in soup.select("li"):
    #how would i do this:
    foo = child_of("li", "div.foo")????
    bar = child_of("li", "div.bar")????
    baz = child_of("li", "div.baz")????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `element:nth-of-type(n)` like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = """<!-- Simplified example of the structure -->
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="foo">foo1 content</div>
        <div class="bar">bar1 content</div>
        <div class="baz">baz1 content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- We can't assume that foo, bar, and baz will always be there -->
        <div class="foo">foo2 content</div>
        <div class="baz">baz2 content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="foo">foo3 content</div>
        <div class="bar">bar3 content</div>
        <div class="baz">baz3 content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
"""

s = BeautifulSoup(a)
s2 = s.select('ul > li:nth-of-type(2)')[0]
foo, bar, baz = s2.select('div.foo'), s2.select('div.bar'), s2.select('div.baz')
print foo, bar, baz
```

Output:

```
[<div class="foo">foo2 content</div>] [] [<div class="baz">baz2 content</div>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for li in soup.select('li'):
    foo = li.select('.foo')
    bar = li.select('.bar')
    baz = li.select('.baz')
```

each time you iterate over the `li` tag and use the `select()`, the html code to be selected is only the li tag's content, like:

```
<li>
    <div class="foo">foo content</div>
    <div class="bar">bar content</div>
    <div class="baz">baz content</div>
</li>
```

So, you can use `select()` to select li's child because li only contains the child tag.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and all the foos, bars and bazs are being stored in separate lists

```
foos = []
bars = []
bazs = []
for i in soup.find_all('li'):
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(i))
    print soup2
    for _ in soup2.find_all('div', {'class':'foo'}):
        foos.append(_)
    for _ in soup2.find_all('div', {'class': 'bar'}):
        bars.append(_)
    for _ in soup2.find_all('div', {'class': 'baz'}):
        bazs.append(_)
```